# I need to Set Value the get URL in a cell

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am now need to convert the Google Sheet page to PDF, email to user and save the PDF format straightway to Google Drive.

And i need the Google Drive link after save it to Google Drive.

The steps from convert the Google Sheet to PDF, and i've done but I've stuck at getting the URL to be paste on the specific cells.

i know to get the URL using this code `Logger.log(fileUrl)`
But how to paste on cell the command ?

```
var changedFlag = false;
var TEMPLATESHEET='Boom-Report';

function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  //Utilities.sleep(300000); //to pause for 60 seconds . Make sure photo completely upload to google sheet
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();

  // This is the link to my spreadsheet with the Form responses and the Invoice Template sheets
  // Add the link to your spreadsheet here 
  // or you can just replace the text in the link between "d/" and "/edit"
  // In my case is the text: 17I8-QDce0Nug7amrZeYTB3IYbGCGxvUj-XMt8uUUyvI
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NVJOdFLBAgNFqSHhnHJYybjUlSqhv4hKI_HXJyhJ88E/edit");

  // We are going to get the email address from the cell "B7" from the "Invoice" sheet
  // Change the reference of the cell or the name of the sheet if it is different
  const value = ss.getSheetByName("Source Email-Boom").getRange("X3").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();

  // Subject of the email message
  const subject = ss.getSheetByName("Source Email-Boom").getRange("B3").getValue();

    // Email Text. You can add HTML code here - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  const body = "Boom Lifts Inspection Report - Sent via Auto Generate PDI Report from Glideapps";

  // Again, the URL to your spreadsheet but now with "/export" at the end
  // Change it to the link of your spreadsheet, but leave the "/export"
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NVJOdFLBAgNFqSHhnHJYybjUlSqhv4hKI_HXJyhJ88E/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
    '&size=A4' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=1832955909'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.
    // You can find the sheet ID in the link bar. 
  // Select the sheet that you want to print and check the link,
  // the gid number of the sheet is on the end of your link.
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // Generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // Send the PDF file as an attachement 
    GmailApp.sendEmail("biha@equip-inc.com", subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: ss.getSheetByName("Source Email-Boom").getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });

  // Save the PDF to Drive. (in the folder) The name of the PDF is going to be the name of the Company (cell B5)
  const nameFile = ss.getSheetByName("Source Email-Boom").getRange("B3").getValue().toString() +".pdf"
  const folderID = "1ZKWq9jWmeEQlxncuTPHssCFXC3Fidmxn";
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).createFile(response).setName(nameFile);



// create file URL

  var SpreadsheetID = "1NVJOdFLBAgNFqSHhnHJYybjUlSqhv4hKI_HXJyhJ88E";
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetID);
  var Sheetname2= "BL-Inspection Report";
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName(Sheetname2);   
  // Get the last row based on the data range of a single column.
  var lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn2 = sheet2.getLastColumn();

  //EXAMPLE: Get the data range based on our selected columns range.
  var dataRange2 = sheet2.getRange(1,1, lastRow2, lastColumn2);
  var dataValues2 = dataRange2.getValues();
  var dataMatch=[];
  //***** */
  // Loop through array and if condition met, add relevant
  // background color.
  var p=34 ; //Column No. for Name column AI:AI (Report No)
 
  

   var filename = encodeURI(nameFile);
   var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nameFile);
   while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      if (file) {
         var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
         
      };
   };
////////////////HELP THIS PART////////////////////////////////
for ( j = 0 ; j < lastRow2 ; j++){
    var zz=j;
    var yy=dataValues2[j][34];
    
    if(dataValues2[j][34] == subject){
      var doclink = Logger.log(fileUrl);
       var range = sheet2.getRange(j+1, 128);       
      range.setValue(doclink);
 
    };
  };

}
```

If cell B3 value in First Source is find in Google Drive, paste the URL in Column DX where the AI is same with First Source.

[image: First Source]
[image: Second Source]

Comment: How are the tags `c++` and `excel` related to your question?

Comment: Is Excel used in your process? If not why did you tag it?

Comment: No, i just click what's recommended.  @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I've stuck at getting the URL to be paste on the specific cells.`, where cell do you want to put the URL?

Comment: @Tanaike the var range . That was the cell i need to put the URL .  var range = sheet2.getRange(j+1, 128);

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `var range = sheet2.getRange(j+1, 128);`, you want to put the same URLs to the several cells. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, if the file name is the same. Then put the URL according to the file name

Comment: @Tanaike And also, if got more than 1 same name file in Google Drive which file it will choose ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `No, if the file name is the same. Then put the URL according to the file name`. And about `And also, if got more than 1 same name file in Google Drive which file it will choose ?`, is this 2nd question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240951/discussion-between-biha-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your effort. 
No, Thats the other condition thats to be consider.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `No, Thats the other condition thats to be consider.`, I understood it. In your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations of the Spreadsheet as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike , I've update the image . Please have a look :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `if got more than 1 same name file in Google Drive which file it will choose ?`, in this case, how will you do? Unfortunately, I cannot know that when the same filenames are existing, how do you want to do from `if got more than 1 same name file in Google Drive which file it will choose ?`. I deeply apologize for this. For example, you want to put the URL of the just created file?

Comment: @Tanaike No problemmmm

Comment: For example, you want to put the URL of the just created file?

Comment: Yes, but my problem is what if the file name already exist . Which file did the script will choose?

Comment: In your script, the oldest file is always retrieved as `fileUrl`. So I cannot understand what file do you want to retrieve. I apologize for this.

Comment: For my question of `For example, you want to put the URL of the just created file?`, from `Yes` of your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to search the file of filename `subject` retrieved from the cell "B3" of "Source Email-Boom" sheet from your Google Drive, and when the value of `subject` is found from the column "AI" of "BL-Inspection Report" sheet, you want to put the URL of the file to the column "AJ".
- For my question of `For example, you want to put the URL of the just created file?`, from `Yes` of your replying, I understood that you wanted to put the URL of the just created file in this script.

In this case, how about the following modification? I thought that in this case, the file URL of the just created file can be directly retrieved from `DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).createFile(response).setName(nameFile)`. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).createFile(response).setName(nameFile);
```

#### To:

```
var fileUrl = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).createFile(response).setName(nameFile).getUrl();
```

And also, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var filename = encodeURI(nameFile);
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nameFile);
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   if (file) {
      var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
      
   };
};
////////////////HELP THIS PART////////////////////////////////
for (j = 0; j < lastRow2; j++) {
  if (dataValues2[j][34] == subject) {
    var doclink = Logger.log(fileUrl);
    var range = sheet2.getRange(j + 1, 128);
    range.setValue(doclink);
  };
};
```

#### To:

```
var range = sheet2.getRange("AI2:AI" + sheet2.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(subject).findNext();
if (range) {
  range.offset(0, 1).setValue(fileUrl);
}
```

- In this modification, the cell is searched using TextFinder.

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: Wowww.. Its work!!! But  but. if the file name got more than two files, which file will be chosen ?

Comment: @Biha Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `But but. if the file name got more than two files, which file will be chosen ? `, in the above modification, even when the same filenames are existing, `fileUrl` of the just created file is always used. I understood that this situation is the result you expect. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: This problem was solved! Thank you so much ! you deserved a Trophy ! I have another issue but related to this one. can i ask here or i have to make another question ?

Comment: @Biha Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.